# Labview CY7C68013A-56 USB Microcontroller High-Speed USB Peripheral Controller

Tags: usb, fpga, xilinx, labview

i need to konw how to make labview get data from "CY7C68013A-56 USB Microcontroller High-Speed USB Peripheral Controller" which is connectoed to xilinx spartan 6

Comment: This sees like a question in the nature of please do my work for me. What have you tried and what specific problem did you run into that has you stuck. If you think that there are different methods and don't know which one to use describe the different methods and ask which one is preferable in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

the general setup is displayed in http://www.cypress.com/file/44551/download on page 2 ( source code is on http://www.cypress.com/documentation/application-notes/an61345-designing-ez-usb-fx2lp-slave-fifo-interface )

> FX2LP Code Architecture
>
> The  firmware  configures  auto mode for both the IN and OUT endpoint FIFOs.
> This  means that the packets  are committed  automatically  from  the
> external peripheral   to  the  USB  domain  for IN transfers  and
> vice versa  for OUT transfers. The  8051 CPU is not involved in
> committing  packets. Refer  Slave  FIFOs  chapter  in EZ - USB
> Technical Reference Manual to get more details on configuration of
> endpoint FIFOs in auto or manual mode.  As bulk transfers are being
> used in this application, you need to configure the endpoints as Bulk.
> But based on the end application you  can configure endpoint type as
> Interrupt, Control, or Isochronous in the USB descriptor file.

so you can get the data from the fpga directly via the USB endpoints `EP2` (OUT) and `EP6` (IN) of the FX2LP via *bulk transfer*

important is page 3 of http://www.cypress.com/file/44551/download because there is information about how to configure the FX2LP, pages 10 to 23 are also important, what is done with the program *USB Control Center* there has to be reproduced with labview

for this you have to connect labview to the endpoints, EP2 as OUT ( from labview pc to FX2LP ) and EP6 as IN ( from FX2LP to labview pc ) as *bulk transfer*

this is done by *NI-VISA*, details are in

- **http://www.cypress.com/forum/psoc-3-known-problems-and-solutions/interfacing-psoc-fx2lp-labview-using-ni-visa-drivers**  <---
- **http://www.ni.com/tutorial/4478/de/**   <---
- http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/370131S-01/ni-visa/usingnivisatocommunicatewithyourusbdevice/
- http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/400D6EAB5CFE1C6B86257395005F5D48

you have to configure the FX2LP correctly and get the VID ( vendor id ) and PID ( product id ) of your FPGA and modify the driver with it

( http://www.cypress.com/file/126446/download ( http://www.cypress.com/documentation/technical-reference-manuals/ez-usb-technical-reference-manual )

( in http://www.cypress.com/documentation/application-notes/an4053-streaming-data-through-isochronous-or-bulk-endpoints-ez-usb is a pc application for USB bulk transfer ( not labview ) )